# How to clear the cookies in a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, cookies

How do you clear the cookies in a Cordova app?

In particular, I want to make sure all cookies set by the servers in the iframes contained in the app are cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin](https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin) does the job. Please note that it works for both PhoneGap and Cordova.

As said in the documentation, after installing the plugin you may call this code:

```
window.cookies.clear(function() {
  console.log('Cookies cleared!');
});
```

Comment: I have just add this plugin, and when generating the app with ionic, the "cookies" parameter is undefined :/.
There is something more to do, apart of adding the plugin? >_<

Comment: I have tje same problem